для чего режим компиляции в VS при помощи Runtime?
программа 1с разработанная в том числе и под Windows . Она явно разработана с использованием IDE - VS с++. но скомпилирована она таким образом , что исталлятор устанавливает кроме exe-шника и собственных dll-ок разработанных 1с ещё и VS рантаймы.
это всевозможные vs redistributable.
Меня вот интересует , что это за вариант компиляции такой ? почему потребовалось делать так ???
Я, конечно, на VS в основном разрабатывал только консольные приложеница , алгоритмы и т.п. оконные приложения не разрабатывал, но что может заставить сделать именно так ? И почему моя консольный проект с внешней сортировкой такого не требует ?

Ваш проект работает на вашей машине и на любой другой машине где установлена VS вашей версии. Если вы запустите ваш проект где-то где VS не установлена, он не стартует, так как ему нужен рантайм. То есть, если вы захотите чтобы ваш проект мог работать везде, вам надо будет добавить к скомпилированному приложению рантайм, что 1С и делает. Я всё упростил, но в целом картина такая.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy
я почему-то думал, что он прячет всё необходимое в exe-шник. плюс всевозможные dll входящие в комплект windows (kernel32.dll). И cтранно ведь я могу скомпилировать свою несчастную сортировку не при помощи VS, а скажем при помощи  g++. Там тоже я должен эти подобные библиотеки подсунуть ?

Да, для программ собранных GCC (на винде) приходится вместе с ними таскать libgcc__.dll, libstdc++__.dll, и иногда libwinpthread__.dll.

@HolyBlackCat спасибо

Есть статическая линковка, когда исполнимый модуль содержит в себе необходимые компоненты рантайма. Этого избегают, так как увеличивается размер модуля, замедляется его старт, нельзя поправить ошибку в рантайме, если она будет найдена позже. По умолчанию линковка динамическая, исполнимый модуль зависит от предустановленного рантайма.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy ну а что например описывается в этих в этих рантаймах ? где - то читал, что функции stl и даже низкоуровневые new , delete. И ещё вопрос , я полагаю , что всякие там кнопочки , checkBox-ы и прочие в голой VS не описаны, чтобы написать тупо окно с меню и окошком about потребуется целая простыня на WinAPI. в райнтамах не описаны WinAPI случайно ?

В рантайме вся стандартная бибиотека языка: управление памятью, STL, ввод/вывод, доступ к средствам ОС. Если вы задействуете GUI, в рантайм включается соответствующая dll. Но WinAPI - другое дело. Библиотеки WinAPI - кусок Windows, они есть на всех компьютерах, где стоит Windows.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy всё спасибо , разъяснили.
